# Difference in abstract class implementation in c# and php

Tags: c#, php, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

I've been working with PHP for a while now I am trying to explore the world of c#.I was trying to understand the abstract class implementation in c sharp.I've found some fluctuation in behavior in both languages.That's why I am posting it here so that I can get a better insight of abstract class implementation in C#.

Both PHP and C# extends abstract class.That means all the class that extends from abstract class must implement the abstract methods as well as inherit non-abstract public methods from abstract class.

The problem arises while accessing the property of child class from a method of the abstract class. In PHP `getHairColor()` can access the public hair property. But in C# `getHairColor()` can't access the public hair property of the class that extends from abstract class.

I think as the Male class extends Person class, it also inherits the `getHairColor()` method from the parent class.So, it should be able to access the hair property. Here PHP implementation makes more sense than C#. Can I get a proper explanation for different behavior for a similar concept in two different languages?

**PHP:**

```
abstract class Person{
    abstract public function setHairColor($color);

    public function getHairColor(){
        return $this->hair;  // $this->hair is accessible from here
    }
}

class Male extends Person{
    public $hair;

    public function setHairColor($color){
        $this->hair = $color;
    }

}

$male1 = new Male();
$male1->setHairColor("black");
echo $male1->getHairColor(); // access hair property
```

**C#:**

```
abstract class Person
{
    public abstract void setHairColor(string hair);

    public string getHairColor()
    {
        return this.hair; // this.hair is not accessible from here
    }

}

class Male : Person
{
    public string hair;

    public override void setHairColor(string hair)
    {
        this.hair = hair;
    }
}

Male male1 = new Male();
male1.setHairColor("black");
Console.WriteLine(male1.getHairColor()); // can not access hair property
```

Comment: No, properties that you define in children are not accessible from the parent. If all `Person`s have hair, why don't you define `hair` in `Person`?

Comment: What will happen in PHP if you extend `Person` and don't define `hair`?

Comment: But it is extending from abstract class.So getHairColor is an inherited method for child class.That's why i think it should access hair property.So,which language is more logical regarding the implementation of abstract class concept.

Comment: Why would your (abstract) base class know anything about its children? If you find that logical, you're saying that if I implement `Dog : Animal`, and a `Dog` can bark, all of a sudden, I can make all `Animal.Bark()`, just because I defined `Bark();` in one of its descendants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# has static typing. That's why you can't access a field or property that is declared in a subclass. You have to declare `Hair` as an abstract property in `Person` and implement it in the subclass:

```
    abstract class Person
    {
        public abstract void SetHairColor(string hair);

        public abstract string Hair { get; }

        public string getHairColor()
        {
            return this.Hair; // now it is accessible
        }

    }

    class Male : Person
    {
        private string _Hair;
        public override string Hair { get { return _Hair; } }

        public override void SetHairColor(string hair)
        {
            this._Hair = hair;
        }
    }
```

You can also implement `SetHairColor` as setter of the property `Hair`:

```
    abstract class Person
    {
        public abstract string Hair { get; set; }

        public string getHairColor()
        {
            return this.Hair; // now it is accessible
        }

    }

    class Male : Person
    {
        private string _Hair;
        public override string Hair 
        { 
            get { return _Hair; } 
            set { _Hair = value }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for you reply.You mentioned the term static typing. But can you explain what does static typing have to do for this behavior ?

Comment: For a general explanation of the term _static typing_, you might look into this: https://csharp.2000things.com/tag/static-typing/ , or this: http://www.alorelang.org/doc/typeoverview.html

Comment: C# accepts only those references that can be resolved at compile-time. If the field `hair` is not declared in the abstract class, how should the compiler know that there's a field `hair`in all possible subclasses? You might somewhere define a subclass `BaldHead` that doesn't have a field `hair`. But declaring an abstract property `Hair` in `Person` ensures that all sublasses implement such a property. In languages with dynamic typing, this would be checked at runtime, and if you tried to access the hair of a `BaldHead`, you'd get a runtime-error.